# How can I force Rails to only use TLS over SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

We are being forced to only use TLS instead of SSL when sending a request to a server, but we don't know how to make sure that the request is being sent using TLS, and if it's not, we're not sure how to force Rails to do it.

Here is how we are sending the request:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://someurl.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
request.body = body
http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
http.ssl_options = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION
```

Comment: `#ssl_options` can be set to a bitmask of constants, which are just wrappers around the equivalent defines in the underlying `include/openssl/ssl.h`. The first two disable SSLv2 and SSLv3, respectively, and the last option disables compression, presumably to mitigate the CRIME attack and other downgrades (SSLv3 _requires_ compression).